# Set image for windows mobile emulator camera

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I am busy developing a windows mobile application that is targeted at WM6 , one of the features i need to use is the camera. In the emulator i can test the camera fine but the image is always black(fades between black and white). I need a way to provide the emulator with a image that i have already taken. At the moment to test i have to deploy the app to my physical device and this is slowing down the process alot.

Comment: It would be easier to create a mock "take picture" method that will return any image you want. For testing replace CaptureDialog with this method.

Answer (score 1):

During testing (on the emulaor) use the image picker instead of the camera.

Comment: I have done that , but i don't want to have to remove it every time i need to deploy (The user can never select an old picture).

Comment: I would : 1. Only do it in the debug build so the release build will never do it, 2. and/or detect if it's running under the emulator then do the image picker...